# Oracle missing expression error occur when i try to insert values into table

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to insert values into my properties table and this missing expression error occur. i can not find any mistake. can someone help me with what i do wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two consecutive commas in this line:

```
SELECT 10993, 11, 'Commercial', 'To lease', 4000 ,'Very nice place to do business',, 002909 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                                                                  ^^ 
                                                                                  here
```